# Can't figure out error while running CVB0Driver in Mahout

Tags: mahout

I've been trying for the last few hours to get CVB0Driver working and after much trial and error I've come to the following error which I can't figure out. (Using mahout-integration 0.7)

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
at org.apache.mahout.math.function.Functions.mult(Functions.java:770)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.lda.cvb.TopicModel.<init>(TopicModel.java:139)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.lda.cvb.TopicModel.<init>(TopicModel.java:113)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.lda.cvb.TopicModel.<init>(TopicModel.java:108)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.lda.cvb.TopicModel.<init>(TopicModel.java:92)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.lda.cvb.CachingCVB0Mapper.setup(CachingCVB0Mapper.java:103)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
```

Here's the code I'm using, since I have yet to get it working I'm not sure if I'm on the right path, so feel free to comment if you see a mistake I'm making.

```
String [] args = {"-c","UTF-8","-i",input,"-o",output};

//create the seq file from the directory of text documents
ToolRunner.run(new SequenceFilesFromDirectory(),args);

//tokenize the documents
DocumentProcessor.tokenizeDocuments(new Path(inputDir), analyzer.getClass().asSubclass(Analyzer.class), tokenizedPath, conf);

//create tf vectors
DictionaryVectorizer.createTermFrequencyVectors(tokenizedPath,new Path(outputDir), DictionaryVectorizer.DOCUMENT_VECTOR_OUTPUT_FOLDER, conf, minSupport, maxNGramSize, minLLRValue, -1.0f, true, reduceTasks, chunkSize, sequentialAccessOutput, true);

//calculate the document frequencies 
Pair<Long[], List<Path>> dfData = TFIDFConverter.calculateDF( new Path(outputDir, DictionaryVectorizer.DOCUMENT_VECTOR_OUTPUT_FOLDER), new Path(outputDir), conf, chunkSize);

//create tfidf vectors
TFIDFConverter.processTfIdf( new Path(outputDir , DictionaryVectorizer.DOCUMENT_VECTOR_OUTPUT_FOLDER), new Path(outputDir), conf, dfData, minDf, maxDFPercent, norm, true, sequentialAccessOutput, true, reduceTasks);

args = new String[]{"-i","tfidf-vectors/part-r-00000","-o","cvb"};

//create the matrix for cvb
RowIdJob.main(args);

CVB0Driver.run(conf, new Path("cvb/matrix"), mto, numTopics, numTerms, alpha, eta, maxIterations, iterationBlockSize, convergenceDelta, dictionaryPath, dto, msto, randomSeed, testFraction, numTrainThreads, numUpdateThreads, maxItersPerDoc, numReduceTasks, backfillPerplexity);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, seems this was some conflict between maven/eclipse projects.

I had recently imported the mahout-integration 0.7 source into eclipse and somehow badly built it, there was issues with mahout-math and my other project maybe started referencing the badly built jar, I'm not too familiar with maven so I don't know if that was the case or eclipse just went a bit crazy.

After deleting this project from eclipse, everything started to run fine.

This question helped resolve this one - [java-unresolved-compilation-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124788/java-unresolved-compilation-problem)