# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error.unresolved compilation

Tags: java, exception

After adding my own jars, I tried to run my code, but appeared this message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error.unresolved compilation problem: at TestCoreNLP.main(TestCoreNLP.java:26).

---

```
package Test;public class TestCoreNLP {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object, with POS tagging, lemmatization, NER, parsing, and coreference resolution
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props); // read some text in the text variable
    String text = "Add your text here:Beijing sings Lenovo";

    // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

    // run all Annotators on this text
    pipeline.annotate(document);

    // these are all the sentences in this document
    // a CoreMap is essentially a Map that uses class objects as keys and has values with custom types
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

    System.out.println("word\tpos\tlemma\tner");
    for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
         // traversing the words in the current sentence
         // a CoreLabel is a CoreMap with additional token-specific methods
        for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
            // this is the text of the token
            String word = token.get(TextAnnotation.class);
            // this is the POS tag of the token
            String pos = token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
            // this is the NER label of the token
            String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);
            String lemma = token.get(LemmaAnnotation.class);

            System.out.println(word+"\t"+pos+"\t"+lemma+"\t"+ne);
        }
        // this is the parse tree of the current sentence
        Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);

        // this is the Stanford dependency graph of the current sentence
        SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
    }
    // This is the coreference link graph
    // Each chain stores a set of mentions that link to each other,
    // along with a method for getting the most representative mention
    // Both sentence and token offsets start at 1!
    Map<Integer, CorefChain> graph = document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class);
}
```

}

Comment: which line is line 26? There is an compile error.

Comment: Welcome, Eng. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124788/java-unresolved-compilation-problem

Comment: line 26 is (public static void main(String[] args) {}). previous lines are libraries.

Comment: provide the whole console output, It might help us determine what the problem is.