# Can´t use JFrame in Eclipse for mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swing

I am new with programming, so sorry if I use the wrong terms or so. I am programming on a macbook air and use Eclipse, but when I tried to import the javax.swing and java.awt, it doesn´t work and I receive an error message (see below). I have done a lot of research and found that some people have similar problems, but since I am a beginner I honestly don't understand the answers (like "removing swt.jar from the project dependencies"). If you know what I can do I would be so grateful for a solution. Here is the program I tried and the error messages that occurred.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;



    class WindowTest extends JFrame

    {
        public WindowTest (){
            super ("Hi");
            setSize (300,100);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible (true);

            Container contentArea = getContentPane();
            contentArea.setBackground(Color.white);

            FlowLayout flowManager = new FlowLayout();
            contentArea.setLayout(flowManager);

            JLabel TextLabel = new JLabel ("I am here");
            contentArea.add(textLabel);

            JLabel TextLabel2 = new Jlabel ("OK");
            contentArea.add(TextLabel2);

            JTextField textBox = new JTextField ("Write here",20);
            contentArea.add(textBox);

            JTextArea comments = new JTextArea ("Comments please",3,20);
            contentArea.add(comments);

            JButton pointlessButton = new JButton ("Exit");
            contentArea.add(pintlessButton);

        }
    }


public class TestWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WindowTest Win = new WindowTest();
    }

}
```

And the error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Access restriction: The type JFrame is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The constructor JFrame(String) is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The method setDefaultCloseOperation(int) from the type JFrame is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The type JFrame is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The field EXIT_ON_CLOSE from the type JFrame is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The method getContentPane() from the type JFrame is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The type JLabel is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The constructor JLabel(String) is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The type JLabel is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
textLabel cannot be resolved
Access restriction: The type JLabel is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Jlabel cannot be resolved to a type
Access restriction: The type JTextField is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The constructor JTextField(String, int) is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The type JTextField is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The type JTextArea is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The constructor JTextArea(String, int, int) is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The type JTextArea is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The type JButton is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The constructor JButton(String) is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
Access restriction: The type JButton is not accessible due to restriction on required library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar
pintlessButton cannot be resolved

at WindowTest.<init>(TestWindow.java:6)
at TestWindow.main(TestWindow.java:43)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have java installed?

Comment: this is a problem of permissions with your JDK in your system.

Comment: Try to clean and re-build your project.... "Project | Clean... | All"

Comment: See this similar question: [Java: Unresolved compilation problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124788/java-unresolved-compilation-problem)

Comment: I do have Java installed, but I have two different versions. Do you think it will improve if I uninstall one of them?

Answer (score 0):

May be the directory in which your classes has placed have access restriction go ahead and give permission 777 to your java directory.
Beside that, this doesn't signify any mac related issue.

you can use "sudo chmod -R 777 ~directory_path"