# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<?> to List<String>

Tags: java, eclipse

I found similar questions but they are not solving my problem.

I have a Java application that is working on the Windows platform and I can debug it with Eclipse, but it does not work on Linux (issues related to the code itself).

I want to debug it in the Linux Eclipse environment but I am getting strange errors that I did not get when I debugged it on Linux.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to List
>       Cannot instantiate the type ArrayList
>       Syntax error on token "<", ? expected after this token

I know that I am supposed to import these:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.List;
```

and they are imported.

Any clue someone?

Comment: I meant the errors did not exist when I debugged it on windows but they appear in linux  version of eclipse/java

Comment: Are you running the same version of Java JDK on both platforms?

Comment: Are you using the same Java versions? Are the same libraries installed? How are you sure the Linux Java is not corrupted?

Comment: Can you include the relevant code using those imports?

Answer (score 2):

You might be **using** `java.awt.List;` instead of `java.util.List;`

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error is thrown regardless which platform you use. If you succeeded to run it on windows then it only means that you didn't run the method which originally failed to compile.

Look at the error's stacktrace and you will find which one is the failing method.

Note: if javac finds an error in a method body, then it still generates the class file, but the problematic method won't do anything just throw an error. This is what happened to your app, and it is meant to happen on any platform.

Comment: Are you saying that javac creates corrupted class files by design?

Comment: @erosb umm... no, if there is an error found at compile time, class file is not created

Comment: yes, exactly. I think it works this way to make non-compiling classes still referrable in some sense. I mean this way if you have MyClassA which doesn't compile and you also have MyClassB which has a member with type MyClassA, MyClassB still compiles (no error for MyClassB.java), since the MyClassA.class binary is created, and the compiler yields error only in MyClassA.java.

This is quite useful during code editing, since a small temporary mistake between two file saves won't redline your entire codebase in the IDE.

The bad part is that the corrupted binary can also be packaged and run.

Comment: do you have some evidence to support your claim that it works that way?

Comment: oops, I was wrong. It is just eclipse and not javac itself behaving this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124788/java-unresolved-compilation-problem