# Dialogs/Alerts in JavaFX8 2.x (Java 8u66)

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, alert

I'm trying to create Dialogs using this code with controls FX:

```
        // Show the error message.
        Dialogs.create()
            .title("Invalid Fields")
            .masthead("Please correct invalid fields")
            .message(errorMessage)
            .showError();
```

But not works. Later i read that controls FX not work with Java FX 2.X, so i found `javafx.scene.control.Alert` so i used this code:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
alert.setContentText("I have a great message for you!");

alert.showAndWait();
```

But still not working. I tried to import manually `javafx.scene.control.*` and throws the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Alert cannot be resolved to a type
    Alert cannot be resolved to a type
    AlertType cannot be resolved to a variable
```

what im doing wrong? how can i show an dialog/alert message?
Regards.

Comment: Compile the code once and then try to run it.

Comment: `Alert` was added in javaFX 8u40 > javafx 2.X, see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html)

Comment: My SDK is jfx8_2.1.0.201508240705  so im using java 8u66 but is jfx2.1 (i donwloaded the latest jfx)

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124788/java-unresolved-compilation-problem

Comment: What platform are you on? On most platforms, a Java 8 JDK will include JavaFX 8 (with the same update version number).

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK or Oracle's JDK? OpenJDK doesn't bundle JFX in their official release. They call it [OpenJFX](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/).

Comment: I'm using Oracle JDK

Comment: Where did you get this jfx8_2.1.0.201508240705 from? JavaFX (8) is bundled with the Java SE 8 (Oracle). There is no need to install/ download a separate package for JavaFX. For Alerts you'll need JavaFX 8u40 or greater.

Comment: E(fx)clipse http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html

Comment: e(fx)clipse is an eclipse plugin for developing JavaFX applications. As already noted, you don't need to install JavaFX (and I don't actually see anywhere on the e(fx)clipse site where a JavaFX runtime is provided). If you have installed a different version of JavaFX, remove it and just use the one bundled with the JDK.

Comment: You can donwload a bundle, not only as addon http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html (im using 64 bits version)

Comment: It still doesn't say anything about having a copy of the JavaFX SDK in there.  go to "Project" -> "Properties" and select the "Libraries" tab. What is listed there?

Comment: My library in this project: http://imgur.com/MoVvhuh