# Counter cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm just beginning to learn java, I created an object counter:

```
public class Counter 
{
    private int value;
    public void setCounter(int count)
    {
        value = count;
    }
    public void click()
    {
        value = value + 1;
    }
    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
    public void reset()
    {
        value = 0;
    }
}
```

When I tried to creat an object of  Counter into my Driver class it gave me the error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: Counter cannot be resolved to a type
Counter cannot be resolved to a type
at Driver.main(Driver.java:4)

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counter count = new Counter();
        count.setCounter(0);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is necessary but I use eclipse.

Edit:
I copied and pasted both of the classes into new classes in a different project and it worked so I think it might have something to do with eclipse rather that my code.

Comment: well you are not really importing Counter class at all. Need more information about package structure. import ....Counter; seems to be missing

Comment: I guess it is related to the internal Eclipse compiler as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124788/java-unresolved-compilation-problem

Comment: @MichaelPickett: Java generates no-arg constructor if there are no constructors declared in code.

Comment: If the classes `Counter` and `Driver` are in the same package then you do not need to import class `Counter` at all - classes in the same package automatically can see each other.

Comment: @BelaVizer: true, but even with a missing import the compiler would give an error. This problem looks like a runtime-error instead. Btw the classes could also be both in the default package. My bet is on the Eclipse compiler. Clean build to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have imported your Counter class - not the one from built-in libraries (**org.w3c.dom.css.Counter**).

Answer (score 0):

1. I think both the counter and driver are in different packages.
2. If both the classes are in same package and the counter class may
   not have been saved and so .class is not generated(In eclipse when you save any class then it will generate .class by default)
3. if both the classes in different package then you need to import
   counter class