# Fail on compile errors instead of throwing "Unresolved compilation problem" at run time

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, runtime-error

When compiling Java code with errors in it, Visual Studio Code generates byte code throwing:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem
```

How can this setting be disabled? I would like Visual Studio Code not to generate any byte code for classes containing compilation errors.

For reference: [Eclipse IDE has the same default behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1124806/238421).

Comment: Do you mean disable this exception warning?

Comment: I would like to get a compile time error instead of a run time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a project with sytax error(one kind of compilation error), it will first show as problems:

[image]

Then you can fix the error, or choose to continue by clicking the `Proceed`, the compilation error will be shown in the Terminal:

[image]

So it's indeed separated by compile time or run time.
If there's misunderstanding about your question, please let me know.