# Exception thread in newBlockingStub of gRPC in Java

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I am new to gRPC. After creating java stubs using a proto file, I am getting an exception in the `newBlocking` stub of the generated java stub file when sending a `loginAPI` request from client. The server is starting, but the client getting an exception.

Client code:

```java
userBlockingStub userStub = userGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
```

generated Java stub file:

```java
public static userBlockingStub newBlockingStub(io.grpc.Channel channel) {
    return new userBlockingStub(channel);
}
```

Getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at com.grpc.userGrpc.newBlockingStub(userGrpc.java:106)
at grpcClient.grpcClient.main(grpcClient.java:19)
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Could you give us more info on the exception? Like the message for example

Comment: getting this exception: 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at com.rakuten.grpc.userGrpc.newBlockingStub(userGrpc.java:106)
 at grpcClient.grpcClient.main(grpcClient.java:19)

Comment: you might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124788/java-unresolved-compilation-problem)

Comment: @ClémentJean unfortunately it didnt solve my problem. i have updated my post for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you are trying to implement a `gRPC` communication, so you have probably more than one service(project) that you want them to be communicated.

I myself implemented a separate project `grpc-interface` and added it to the Git repository, then I could add this project as a `submodule` using the `Git-submodule` feature to my services(projects) that I needed to be communicated.

I implemented my `grpc-interface` as below:

here is my `build.gradle` file, you can find the `Maven` version with a little R&D easily too:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        protobufVersion = '3.19.1'
        protobufPluginVersion = '0.8.18'
        grpcVersion = '1.44.0'
        protobufJava = '3.19.4'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version "${protobufPluginVersion}"
}

group = 'com.ada.bourse.grpc-interface'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:${protobufJava}"
    compileOnly 'jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5' // Java 9+ compatibility - Do NOT update to 2.0.0
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protobufVersion}"
    }
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/src/generated"
    clean {
        delete generatedFilesBaseDir
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Then I created a `.proto` file to introduce my service and its request and response model:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package com.ada.bourse.grpc.accounting;

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.ada.bourse.grpc.accounting";

service AccountingService {
  rpc userBalance(UserBalanceRequest) returns (UserBalanceResponse) {
  }
}

message UserBalanceRequest {
  string username = 1;
}

message UserBalanceResponse {
  double balance = 1;
}
```

After this step, you need to compile the project and it will result in creating a package with a `generated` name beside your `main` package.

Then, as I said if you put this project in a repository like Git, you need to add it to your projects using the `Git-submodule` feature, of course, there are other ways to add it to your projects and `Git-submodule` is not a MUST!

****just consider that, after adding this module to your projects, before running and compiling the main project you need to compile your `grpc-interface` so that your project can use generated files that is like:****

[image]

Now I have two services, named `wealth-manager` and `accounting` that I want to be communicated, as you saw in my `.proto` file, I want my `wealth` service to request and check the user balance from my `accounting` service.

in my `wealth` service I did as below in my Service layer:

```
@Service
public class RestrictionServiceImpl implements IRestrictionService {

    @GrpcClient("accounting-service")
    private AccountingServiceGrpc.AccountingServiceBlockingStub accountingServiceStub;

private void checkUserBalanceForBuyOrder(RestrictionFilterCriteria filterCriteria) {
        Double userBalance = getUserBalanceFromAccountingServiceGrpc(filterCriteria.getUsername());
        if (userBalance < filterCriteria.getAmount() * filterCriteria.getPrice())
            throw new RestrictionException(new BaseException.ErrorDetail()
                    .setLoc("balance")
                    .setType(Constant.INSUFFICIENT_BALANCE));
    }

    private Double getUserBalanceFromAccountingServiceGrpc(String username) throws GrpcConnectionException {
        UserBalanceRequest request = UserBalanceRequest.newBuilder()
                .setUsername(username)
                .build();
        return accountingServiceStub.userBalance(request).getBalance();
    }
```

}

And in my `accounting` service I have created class for `grpc` services as below:

```
@GrpcService
public class AccountingServiceGRPC extends AccountingServiceGrpc.AccountingServiceImplBase {

    private final IUserAccountService userAccountService;

    public AccountingServiceGRPC(IUserAccountService userAccountService) {
        this.userAccountService = userAccountService;
    }

    @Override
    public void userBalance(UserBalanceRequest request, StreamObserver<UserBalanceResponse> responseObserver) {
        UserBalanceResponse balanceResponse = UserBalanceResponse.newBuilder()
                .setBalance(userAccountService.getUserBalance(request.getUsername()))
                .build();
        responseObserver.onNext(balanceResponse);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

I myself have argued with `gRPC` a lot until I could resolve it, hope my experience with it helps you to resolve yours too.

Comment: @Mahid did my answer help you?